# Binding CalendarDateRange attribute withiin datepicker wpf control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datetime

I have this datepicker in my wpf application :

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDate="{Binding DateP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                        <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                                                <CalendarDateRange    End="01 /01 /02 "/>

                                        </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                                          </DatePicker>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I'd like to bind the `End` attribute of ***CalendarDateRange*** to a datetime property like this :

```
 <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                    <CalendarDateRange  End="{Binding DateE1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <CalendarDateRange  Start="{Binding DateS1, Mode=TwoWay}"   End="{Binding DateE2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

1. How can I accomplish this task?
2. What is the best idea to do it?